# Make php app scalable - migrate to nosql database?

Tags: php, database, nosql, scalability, bigdata

we are building a social network. We are now focusing on server side coding, and we are at a quite far point. I am now wondering about scalability problems.

Our server applicaion returns to users some infos like the number of utilization of one hashtag in various posts, for example. to do that, instead of fetching all posts each request and controlling if it includes searched hashtag, just each time an hashtag is used in a post (so when post is uploaded) we store this data in a database (increasing a counter, for example). is this approach right for making the application scalable? I know this approach will use more memory, but in this way increasing number of posts and data in general won't affect and make longer the time that server needs to calculate and return the number of utilization of one hasthag. But these are just my theories, i need an hand.

Then, i read about nosql datbases instead of classical sql relational databases. But honestly i didn't get the point. Which is the true advantage of using nosql databases when it comes to big data?

For example i have to run an algorhytm on 100'000 posts/20M posts, to determinate how much they could be interesting for a target user. How a nosql databse could improve the performance of this process? Thank you

Comment: nosql is certainly better at full text searches, which sounds like what you are doing.  Running millions of `LIKE` statements is a performance killer.

Comment: Best way to improve performance / scalability would to be use caching.  Ie calculate once every so often and display the pre calculated value.